# Distinguishing kinds of tracks on the remote end of RTCPeerConnection

Tags: stream, webrtc, peer, rtcpeerconnection

What is a good way to distinguish `track`'s on the remote end of an `RTCPeerConnection` in the `ontrack` event? Say I want to treat microphone tracks differently from the system sound tracks, how do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In WebRTC, how do I label a local MediaStream so that a remote peer can identify it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408744/in-webrtc-how-do-i-label-a-local-mediastream-so-that-a-remote-peer-can-identify)

Comment: Yes, I saw the answer, but wanted to find a better solution than the three proposed. Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky-but-only solution by some Kevin Moreland [here](https://www.kevinmoreland.com/articles/03-22-20-webrtc-mediastream-tracks). Huge thanks, it's the best way i've seen so far. We definitely need a way to do this through WebRtc without hacks